# What is the Difference between querying in a list variable and in a loop

Tags: apex

I have seen way of querying in many ways but does that really make a difference or its  just a way of coding

```
List<CustomObj__c> CustObj = new List<CustomObj__c>();
CustObj = [Select id, Name, CustField1__c, CustField2__c from CustomObj__c];
```

And

```
for(CustomObj__c i : Select id, Name, CustField1__c, CustField2__c from CustomObj__c){}
```

Is there a difference or just a way of writing a code.

Answer (score 5):

There is a nice [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm) about your question. Some quotes from there:

> SOQL for loops differ from standard SOQL statements because of the
>   method they use to retrieve sObjects. While the standard queries
>   discussed in SOQL and SOSL Queries can retrieve either the count of a
>   query or a number of object records, SOQL for loops retrieve all
>   sObjects, using efficient chunking with calls to the query and
>   queryMore methods of the SOAP API. Developers should always use a SOQL
>   for loop to process query results that return many records, to avoid
>   the limit on heap size.
>
> Note that queries including an aggregate function don't support
>   queryMore. A run-time exception occurs if you use a query containing
>   an aggregate function that returns more than 2,000 rows in a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The list object will be in heap till the span of the object in the program and another query which is written in for loop will dereference after the loop span completes.

Here you can use the query result throughout the program(considering object span) and the query result of loop will not be used outside the loop and you have to query once again to get the result.